# Is there a way to process http request in websockets?

Tags: python, http, websocket

I want to allow python `websockets` module to process HTTP request and not only WebSocket formatted requests.

Or i need to write custom http server?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `websockets` package was not designed for this. From the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/):

> #### Why shouldn’t I use `websockets`?
>
> [...]
>
> - If you’re looking for a mixed HTTP / WebSocket library [...]
>
>   If you want to do both in the same server, look at HTTP frameworks that build on top of websockets to support WebSocket connections, like Sanic.

This answer is not an endorsement/recommendation of Sanic; that's just one example which was copied from the `websockets` doc.